# Converting Text Row Data file into Cloumn Data file

Tags: csv

I have a text file with data on movies.

This text file is like csv file and the data is being arranged in rows.

Each movie has multiple records:

```
Movie ID    
Movie Poster 1 Link    
Movie Poster 2 Link    
Movie Trailer Link    
Movie Title    
Movie Label ID    
Movie Year
```

Now the problem is that all records are repeated for each movie except for:

```
Movie Poster 2 Link    
Movie Trailer Link
```

on which there might be a value or might not.

If there is no value for those (2) records, the record itself won't be existing for this particular movie.

There is nothing I can do to fix this. I have to deal with the data in my hand.

I've found a solution to convert the rows in this text file into columns in excel, but my issue now is that I have huge data and it is getting extremely hard to apply the solution in excel directly. This text file with data in rows need to be converted into csv file with data in columns bearing in mind the appearance or disappearance of those (2) records:

```
Movie Poster 2 Link
Movie Trailer Link
```

Appreciate any suggestions to resolve this issue.

below is a sample text file with (5) movies along with their records:

```
Movie ID: 1001;
Movie Poster 1 Link: http ://poster_link1001_a;
Movie Trailer Link: http ://trailer_link1001;
Movie Title: Sleeping Beauty
Movie Label ID: SLEEPING_1001;
Movie Year: (1959);
Movie ID: 1002;
Movie Poster 1 Link: http ://poster_link1002_a;
Movie Title: Superman II
Movie Label ID: SUPERMANII_1002;
Movie Year: (1980);
Movie ID: 1003;
Movie Poster 1 Link: http ://poster_link1003_a;
Movie Poster 2 Link: http ://poster_link1003_b;
Movie Trailer Link: http ://trailer_link1003;
Movie Title: Maverick
Movie Label ID: MAVERICK_1003;
Movie Year: (1994);
Movie ID: 1004;
Movie Poster 1 Link: http ://poster_link1004_a;
Movie Title: Arthur
Movie Label ID: ARTHUR_1004;
Movie Year: (1981);
Movie ID: 1005;
Movie Poster 1 Link: http ://poster_link1005_a;
Movie Trailer Link: http ://trailer_link1005;
Movie Title: Before Sunset
Movie Label ID: BEFORESUNSET_1005;
Movie Year: (2004);
```

and below is how those rows should be converted into columns:

[image: Data Columns]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each piece of data is actually preceded by a descriptor, a colon, and a space? If so it should be trivially easy to write a program to process the data into any additional format that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this in VBA. Create a new module and then type this in:

```
Public Sub ImportFile()

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FileLine As String
    Dim RowToWrite As Integer

    ' This is the file containing the data
    FileName = "C:\test.txt"
    RowToWrite = 1

    ' Open the file
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input As #FileNum

    ' Loop through the file
    While Not EOF(FileNum)

        ' Read the line
        Line Input #FileNum, FileLine

        ' Ask WriteData subroutine to write data
        WriteData "Movie ID:", "A", RowToWrite, FileLine
        WriteData "Movie Poster 1 Link:", "B", RowToWrite, FileLine
        WriteData "Movie Poster 2 Link:", "C", RowToWrite, FileLine
        WriteData "Movie Trailer Link:", "D", RowToWrite, FileLine
        WriteData "Movie Title:", "E", RowToWrite, FileLine
        WriteData "Movie Label ID:", "F", RowToWrite, FileLine
        WriteData "Movie Year:", "G", RowToWrite, FileLine
    Wend

    ' Close the file and inform the user that work is done
    Close #FileNum
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub



Private Sub WriteData(Heading As String, ColumnName As String, ByRef RowToWrite As Integer, FileLine As String)

    ' If the line has the heading we asked for, then do some work
    If InStr(FileLine, Heading) > 0 Then

        ' Remember to go to the next line when Movie ID is found
        If Heading = "Movie ID:" Then
            RowToWrite = RowToWrite + 1
        End If

        ' Remove the heading from the line. Also remove semicolon
        Dim DataToWrite As String
        DataToWrite = Replace(Replace(FileLine, Heading, ""), ";", "")

        ' Movie Year can have paranthesis. Remove them
        If Heading = "Movie Year:" Then
            Range(ColumnName & RowToWrite) = Replace(Replace(DataToWrite, "(", ""), ")", "")
        Else
            Range(ColumnName & RowToWrite) = DataToWrite
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Assuming your file is test.txt, this will process data and start dumping it from row 2 column A. Give it a shot.

**Result is this**

Note, you might have to add your own heading and that's the easy part.

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind support zedfoxus. Works like charm now :)